# Shuffle array and prevent more than 2 in a row

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array being built like this:

```
var entries = ['L','L','L','L','L','L','L','L','L','L','R','R','R','R','R','R','R','R','R','R','M','M','M','M','M']
```

This means the array is always filled with 10 times L, 10 times R and 5 times M

The output I want to achieve is a randomly generated array, so I came up with the simple solution to just shuffle it with

```
function shuffle(o){
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
}
```

The problem I have now is that there is a rule for the outcome, never have one of these letters more than 2 times in a row. So I thought I just use a do/while loop to shuffle until that criteria is met. But in my test runs this totally fails with long loops.

So my question is - what is the best way to build this array without depending on luck. My full program that fails is something like this

```js
function shuffle(o){
  for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
}

function createProgram(numShooters){
    var programs = [];

    for(var s = 0; s < numShooters; s++){

        //Build array with L/R/M
        for( d=0; d < 10; d++ ){
            program.push('L');
            program.push('R');
            if(d < 5){
                program.push('M');    
            }
        }
        
        // This will run way too long and is not reliable
      
        //do{
        //  program = shuffle(program);    
        //}while(!checkProgram(program))
                      
        if(!checkProgram(program)){
            console.log('invalid program at ' + s);
        }

        programs[s] = program;

    }

    return programs;
}

function checkProgram(program){
    var len = program.length;
    var last = null;
    var dups = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<len; len++){
        
        if(program[i] == last){
            dups++;
        }else{
            dups = 0;
        }

        if(dups == 2){
            return false;
        }
        
        last = program[i];
    }

    return true;
}

createProgram(5);
```

Comment: Do you need cryptographically random shuffles, or is pseudo-random good enough? Also, must the generator be able to generate any outcome, or are you okay with a subset based on some extra rules that would make it cheap to generate acceptable shuffles?

Comment: It does not need to be cryptographically at all, but a subset is not working - it really needs to be random programs being built, otherwise it might be predictable which is not allowed in this case.

Comment: a subset would only be predictable in that some shuffles won't be possible

Comment: ah ok that way round, yes you are right - the impossible shuffles can be predictable as this is implicited by the rules.

Comment: OK, so one way to do it would be to shuffle just Ls and Ms, then loop over the result and insert Rs where needed to break streaks of more than 2, and finally get all the legal positions for the remaining Rs and distribute between zero and two of each there. It's possible that the initial shuffle will have more than 10 streaks of more than 2, but so unlikely that you can just reshuffle in that case.

Comment: tip: an efficient way to get a bunch of random numbers, much better than Math.random in a loop, is to do `Array.from(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(25)))` (replace 25 with whatever length you need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just shuffle arrays and hope for one without duplicates, you can create them by picking characters by random and specifically avoid to pick the character that was picked previously.

If you keep track of how many there are left to pick of each character, you can control the odds for the character to pick so that the distribution is correct. If for example the first two characters are L, then there are 10 R and 5 M left to pick from (and 8 L, but they are excluded for the next pick), so there should be a 2 in 3 chance to pick an R and a 1 in 3 chance to pick and M.

This approach can run into a dead end, where the array can't be completed, so it has to start over. Running it a few hundred times I have seen something like a 10% overhead, so if you create five arrays you should by average see a retry every other time.

```js
function createProgram(numShooters){
  var programs = [];

  for(var s = 0; s < numShooters; s++){

    var chars = [ 'L', 'R', 'M' ];
    var program;
    do {
        
      program = [];
      var cnt = [ 10, 10, 5, 0 ]; // picks left
      var prev = 3; // previous pick
      var tot = 25; // total picks left
      while (program.length < 25) {
        // check for duplicates
        var x = program.length >= 2 && program[program.length - 2] == program[program.length - 1] ? prev : 3;
        // check if more picks are possible
        if (tot - cnt[x] <= 0) {
          console.log('invalid program ' + program);
          break;
        }
        // pick from the possible
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tot - cnt[x]));
        // determine what character was picked
        var c = 0;
        while (c == x || r >= cnt[c]) {
          if (c != x) r -= cnt[c];
          c++;
        }
        program.push(chars[c]);
        cnt[c]--;
        tot--;
        prev = c;
      }

    } while (program.length < 25);

    programs[s] = program;

  }

  return programs;
}

console.log(createProgram(1).toString());
```

Comment: Ok, that answer is totally fine and worked out when testing. But I also wrote a version that is based on what @Touffy suggested. I will accept yours as it is shorter and also your effort in answering my question should be honored

Answer (score 0):

So this is the final solution I came up with, as commented Guffas solution also works nice and smooth. But after doing some tests mine is about 30% faster and more readable, but way longer so I'll accept Guffas - thanks to everybody for their input!

```
function createProgram(numShooters){
    var programs = [];

    for(var s = 0; s < numShooters; s++){

        var program = buildProgram();
        programs[s] = program;

    }

    return programs;
}

function buildProgram(){
    var program = [];
    var ls = fillArray('L',10);
    var rs = fillArray('R',10);
    var ms = fillArray('M',5);

    //Use either L or R to mix into M - adds variation
    var side = Math.random() > 0.5 ? ls : rs;
    var otherSide = side == ls ? rs : ls;
    var initProg = side.concat(ms);
    initProg = shuffle(initProg);

    var program = [];

    //Correcting invalid positions as suggested
    for(var p1 = 0; p1 < initProg.length; p1++){
        if(p1 > 1 && initProg[p1-1] == initProg[p1-2] && initProg[p1-1] == initProg[p1]){
            if(otherSide.length > 0){
                program.push(otherSide.pop());    
            }else{
                return buildProgram(); //impossible state, redo...
            }
        }
        program.push(initProg[p1]);
    }

    //Fill into remaining other pos
    for(var p2 = 0; p2 < otherSide.length; p2++){
        program = addAtRandomPos(program,otherSide[p2]);
    }

    return program;
}

function addAtRandomPos(arr,chr){
    var pos = getRandomInt( 0, arr.length - 1 );
    var charCur = arr[pos];

    var pprev = pos > 1 ? arr[pos-2] : null;
    var prev  = pos > 0 ? arr[pos-1] : null;
    var next  = pos < arr.length - 1 ? arr[pos] : null;
    var nnext = pos < arr.length - 2 ? arr[pos+1] : null;

    var str = pprev + prev + chr + next + nnext;

    if(str.indexOf('MMM') !== -1 || str.indexOf('RRR') !== -1 || str.indexOf('LLL') !== -1){
        return addAtRandomPos(arr,chr);
    }else{
        arr.splice(pos,0,chr);
    }

    return arr;

}

function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function fillArray(chr,num){
    var arr = [];
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(chr);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Trying that code out I saw that it didn't eliminate duplicates at all, so I checked the question and I see that I have solved a problem that is harder than the one requested. My code made sure there are never two of the same letters in a row, while it only had to make sure that there are never *more than* two in a row. I adjusted the code in the answer to fit that, which also makes it more efficient as there are lot fewer retries.